# Need SQL query for following:

Tags: mysql, sql

```
bug_id     ops_status   partition_date
32307107    ARCHIVED    2017-04-14
32307107    ARCHIVED    2017-04-13
32307107    ARCHIVED    2017-04-12
32307107    ARCHIVED    2017-04-11
32307107    ARCHIVED    2017-04-10
32307107    ARCHIVED    2017-04-09
32307107    ARCHIVED    2017-04-08
32307107    ARCHIVED    2017-04-07
32307107    ARCHIVED    2017-04-06
32307107    PREPUBLISH  2017-04-05
32307107    PREPUBLISH  2017-04-04
32307107    PREPUBLISH  2017-04-03
32307107    PREPUBLISH  2017-04-02
32307107    PREPUBLISH  2017-04-01
32307107    ARCHIVED    2017-03-31
32307107    ARCHIVED    2017-03-30
32307107    ARCHIVED    2017-03-29
32307107    ARCHIVED    2017-03-28
32307107    ARCHIVED    2017-03-27
32307107    ARCHIVED    2017-03-26
```

I need last ops_status i.e ARCHIVED and when it is updated i.e "2017-04-06"  - so the `"32307107    ARCHIVED    2017-04-06"` row from the above data. Can some one please help me.

Comment: Where is the Problem?

Comment: mysql or SQL-Server?

Comment: Your question is not clear. More détails plsease.

Comment: I need last ops_status i.e ARCHIVED and when it is updated i.e "2017-04-06"

Comment: mysql if possible

Answer (score 0):

```
select bug_id, ops_status, max(partition_date)
 from table1
 where ops_status = 'ARCHIVED'
 group by bug_id,ops_status
```

This is in SQL-Server

Comment: Nope. I want this date "2017-04-06"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the first date that the status changed to "Archived" for a bug_id.  To do that, you can use a subquery to get the latest date that it was NOT archived.  In the main query you can then use MIN to find the earliest Archived date.

```
SELECT bug_id, ops_status, MIN(partition_date)
FROM yourTable AS a
WHERE a.partition_date > 
    (SELECT MAX(partition_date)
    FROM yourTable AS b
    WHERE b.status = 'PREPUBLISH'
      AND a.bug_id = b.bug_id)
```

Comment: Edited - please check